# Why is the content of my pointer to a friend class changing?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an object class "Bag" to store a linked list of object of friend class "Items".
Bag contains a pointer to an "Item" object.
The first call to the content of the Item object is always correct.
However, I am facing some problems as the value called subsequently will never be the same as the value called in the first time.

In other words,
Baseclass.BaseclassMember is constant as expected.
But (Baseclass.FriendClassPointer)->FriendClassMember is changing

Anyone knows why?

```
enum itemtype {potion, poison};

class Item
{
public:
friend class Bag;

Item(itemtype,int);
void initItem();
int qty;
int value;
Item *prevItem, *nextItem;
itemtype type;
};

class Bag
{
public:
Bag(Item,int);
Item *currentItem;
int currentsize;
int maxsize;
};

Item::Item(itemtype ITEMtype, int quantity): type(ITEMtype),qty(quantity)
{
initItem();
prevItem=nullptr;
nextItem=nullptr;
}


void Item::initItem()
{
value=8 ;           
}

Bag::Bag(Item firstItem, int maxbagsize) : currentItem(&firstItem),maxsize(maxbagsize),currentsize(1) 
{
currentItem->nextItem = currentItem;
currentItem->prevItem = currentItem;
cout<<"constructor check: Item Address "<<currentItem<<" nextAddress "<<currentItem->nextItem<<" "<<"\n";
}
```

int main()

```
Item item1(potion,1);
Bag bag1(item1,5);

cout<<" 1st call:"<<" Bagsize "<<bag1.currentsize<<" nextAddress "<<(bag1.currentItem)->nextItem<<"\n";
cout<<" 2nd call:"<<" Bagsize "<<bag1.currentsize<<" nextAddress "<<(bag1.currentItem)->nextItem<<"\n";

getchar(); /* stops window from closing */
return 0;
```

Comment: `currentItem(&firstItem)` is one obvious problem -- you store the address of an object that will be destroyed when the constructor completes.

Comment: Yes, further to what MM says, if you want to program a linked list you need to use dynamic allocation (using `new`) precisely because you can then control when objects get created and destroyed.

Comment: Hi! M.M. Thanks for the tip. I tried changing the constructor argument to take a reference(ie. Item&) and it worked! But then I am confused though. If it was the constructor's fault, wouldn't both COUT streams be printing out rubbish instead of just the second one?

Comment: Hi! John. Actually I am developing this incrementally. Was trying it out with statically declared objects first, of which I am more familiar, before trying it on dynamic objects. But kind of got stuck in this step